# Ayuda con select dinamicos jquery

Tags: html, ajax, select

tengo un problema con unos campos de selección dinámicos,lo que quiero es que al cambiar uno de los select (a) el otro select (b) también se cambie y viceversa, el problema es que debe hacerse utilizando el atributo data-cod, por ejemplo si selecciono la opción 1 del select a, en el select b se debe seleccionar dinámicamente la opción que corresponda con el mismo código del atributo data-cod, dejo el código que llevo por el momento, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

```js
var wrapper_sel = $(".content_select");

$(wrapper_sel).find('select').change(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();              

  var cod = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-cod");
  alert(cod); 

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_select">

  <select id="a">

    <option data-cod="1224" value="1">Opción 1</option>
    <option data-cod="1130" value="2">Opción 2</option> 

  </select>

  <select id="b">

    <option data-cod="1224" value="a">Opción a</option>
    <option data-cod="1130" value="b">Opción b</option> 

  </select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta buscando el option que contenta el un atributo data-cod igual al codigo seleccionado, y luego lo marcas como `selected`.

Asi fue como pude lograrlo:

```js
var wrapper_sel = $(".content_select");

$(wrapper_sel).find('select').change(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();              
  var cod = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-cod");

  $("#b option[data-cod="+cod+"]")[0].selected = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_select">

  <select id="a">

    <option data-cod="1224" value="1">Opción 1</option>
    <option data-cod="1130" value="2">Opción 2</option> 

  </select>

  <select id="b">

    <option data-cod="1224" value="a">Opción a</option>
    <option data-cod="1130" value="b">Opción b</option> 

  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Es lo que estaba buscando, pero tengo otro problema, si deseo seleccionar la opción del select b la opción del select a tambien debe cambiar, no logro dar con esto, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Buenas amigo puedes obtener cualquier propiedad `html data` con jquery usando la `function` `data` seguido de la clave que tienes después del guión.

Ejemplo:

> html

```
<option data-cod="1224" value="1">Opción 1</option>
```

> jquery

```
$(this).find("option:selected").data("cod");
```

Espero te ayude saludos

En el ejemplo la idea es obtener el atributo `data` y compararlo con el mismo atributo del `select` siguiente si coinciden entonces asignarle la propiedad `selected`

```js
var wrapper_sel = $(".content_select");

$(wrapper_sel).find('select').change(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();              
  var cod = $(this).find("option:selected").data("cod");
  $(".content_select select").find("option").each(function(){
    if($(this).data("cod") == cod){
      $(this).prop("selected","true")
    }
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_select">

  <select id="a">

    <option data-cod="1224" value="1">Opción 1</option>
    <option data-cod="1130" value="2">Opción 2</option> 

  </select>

  <select id="b">

    <option data-cod="1224" value="a">Opción a</option>
    <option data-cod="1130" value="b">Opción b</option> 

  </select>

</div>
```